# Invoking server code after client code for a control INSIDE AJAX PANEL - Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik

I've the Javascript code to do a confirmation before deletion of some records

```
function confirmDelete()
{
   if(confirm('Delete all?'))
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

I've the button code here

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" onClientClick="return confirmDelete();" onClick="btnDelete_click" />
```

If i've the button outside an update panel (basically i'm using RadAjaxPanel by Telerik) it is working fine. But when the button is inside an ajax panel, even if i click OK for deleting the records the server side code is not called.

Any ideas?

Comment: Okie, should have searched for some time. Got the answer here - [http://forums.asp.net/p/1486636/3482994.aspx](http://forums.asp.net/p/1486636/3482994.aspx). Dint know about that!

Comment: @tvanfosson - Oh! shouldn't i tell thanks or regards for helping me out?! :)

Comment: the general consensus is to omit saluations and closings on questions, but only to remove them when editing for other reasons.  You can thank me (in a comment) for correcting the spelling of "Invoking."  :-)

Comment: You did that? I thought i did correct it the very next moment. But you guys are too sharp, though! :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is being prepended to the click handler that posts the action back to the server.  You need to check if your result returns true/false then optionally continue executing the server-generated code.

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server"
              onClientClick="if (!confirmDelete()) { return false; }" 
              onClick="btnDelete_click" />
```

This will result in client-side HTML like

```
 <input type="submit" id="btnDelete"
        onclick="if (!confirmDelete()) { return false; } __DoPostBack...
```

allowing the server-generated code to be executed (i.e., no return is evaluated unless the confirmation fails).